# Map and Split the data based on key in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

How can I achieve this in scala

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List(("a", "aaa$$bbb"), ("b", ("ccc$$ddd$$eee"))))
val res1 = a.mapValues(_.replaceAll("\\$\\$", "-"))
```

here I have Array[(String, String)]

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array(("a",aaa-bbb), ("b",ccc-ddd-eee))
```

Now I want the result to be as below

```
1,aaa
1,bbb
2,ccc
2,ddd
2,eee
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
res1.flatMap{ case (k, v) => v.split("-").map((k, _)) }.collect
// res7: Array[(String, String)] = Array((a,aaa), (a,bbb), (b,ccc), (b,ddd), (b,eee))
```

Comment: Great,Thank You Psidom